# Strange MLCP issue: ERROR c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner - Unable to query destination information, no usable hostname found

Tags: azure, marklogic, mlcp

I am using the official MarkLogic Multi-Model Database: Enterprise Edition v.11 image found in Azure Marketplace to set up a CICD pipeline including the 3 node ml cluster infra deployment. That is step 1. After that infra deployment, it will run mlgradle mlDeploy to deploy custom ML set up on that new Infra. That is step 2. The last step (3) is to run MLCP import in archive mode to initialize the db with some selected content.

Step 1 and 2 always work well. But Step 3 (MLCP) will always fail. However, once I run mlUndeploy, Step 2 and Step 3 will always work. What could be the reason? How to overcome it?

My current CICD flow is 1) Build 3Node Cluster 2) mlDeploy 3) MLCP 4) mlUnDeploy 5) mlDeploy 6) MLCP. Step 4-6 is purely for the sake of overcoming that strange MLCP issue.

```
05:03:54.528 [main] INFO  c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner - Content type: XML
05:03:54.775 [main] INFO  c.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump - Job name: local_948621731_1
05:03:54.791 [main] INFO  c.m.c.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 2
05:03:55.366 [main] ERROR c.m.contentpump.ThreadManager - Server cannot accept request: Bad Gateway
com.marklogic.xcc.exceptions.ServerConnectionException: Server cannot accept request: Bad Gateway
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.ServiceUnavailableHandler.handleResponse(ServiceUnavailableHandler.java:37)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.EvalRequestController.serverDialog(EvalRequestController.java:119)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.handlers.AbstractRequestController.runRequest(AbstractRequestController.java:92)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequestInternal(SessionImpl.java:495)
    at com.marklogic.xcc.impl.SessionImpl.submitRequest(SessionImpl.java:490)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ThreadManager.queryServerMaxThreads(ThreadManager.java:143)
    at com.marklogic.mapreduce.MarkLogicOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs(MarkLogicOutputFormat.java:95)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.LocalJobRunner.run(LocalJobRunner.java:126)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runJobLocally(ContentPump.java:356)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.runCommand(ContentPump.java:255)
    at com.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump.main(ContentPump.java:74)
05:03:55.367 [main] WARN  c.m.mapreduce.MarkLogicOutputFormat - Unable to connect to mlcluster-dev-appgateway.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com to query destination information
05:03:55.367 [main] ERROR c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner - Error checking output specification: 
05:03:55.367 [main] ERROR c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner - Unable to query destination information, no usable hostname found
05:08:34.188 [main] INFO  c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner - Content type: XML
05:08:34.498 [main] INFO  c.marklogic.contentpump.ContentPump - Job name: local_2046123866_1
05:08:34.525 [main] INFO  c.m.c.FileAndDirectoryInputFormat - Total input paths to process : 2
05:08:36.227 [Thread-4] INFO  c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner -  completed 0%
05:08:37.228 [Thread-4] INFO  c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner -  completed 50%
05:08:45.299 [Thread-4] INFO  c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner -  completed 100%
05:10:41.595 [main] INFO  c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner - com.marklogic.mapreduce.MarkLogicCounter: 
05:10:41.595 [main] INFO  c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner - INPUT_RECORDS: 1663
05:10:41.595 [main] INFO  c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner - OUTPUT_RECORDS: 1663
05:10:41.595 [main] INFO  c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner - OUTPUT_RECORDS_COMMITTED: 1675
05:10:41.595 [main] INFO  c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner - OUTPUT_RECORDS_FAILED: 0
05:10:41.595 [main] INFO  c.m.contentpump.LocalJobRunner - Total execution time: 127 sec
```

Comment: Have you tried just waiting before running, and not doing the undeploy/redeploy? The error seems like its getting a gateway timeout or unable to resolve that hostname. Maybe try testing the connection to that URL outside of MLCP with curl and verify that it resolves and can connect to mlcluster-dev-appgateway.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com?

Comment: Yes. It works after adding a time delay between Step 2 and Step 3. It does make sense now, as mlDeploy just creates that XCC server in ML cluster. It needs some time to be discoverable in the AppGateway.  Geate thanks.